# How to set json response for server error and timeout in nginx

Tags: nginx

I want to set json response for timeout or internal server error.

```
server {
    server_name 192.168.1.16;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_read_timeout 5s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 5s;
        proxy_send_timeout 6s;
        send_timeout 5s;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /home/oem/PycharmProjects/indiawyn-backend/static;
    }
    location  ^~ /json_files {
        root /home/www/;
    }
}
```

I don't know where to configure that.
Kindly share any doc or ans for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
server {
    ...
    error_page 500 /json_files/500.json;
    error_page 504 /json_files/504.json;
    ...
}
```

In `/home/www/json_files/500.json` and `/home/www/json_files/504.json` files put something like

```
{
  "code": 500,
  "error": "internal_server_error",
  "error_description": "Internal server error"
}
```

,

```
{
  "code": 504,
  "error": "gateway_timeout",
  "error_description": "Gateway timeout"
}
```

If your mime types set up correctly, nginx will automatically add `Content-Type: application/json` header.